# Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Shout.LibSSH2Error.error(-16)

Tags: swift, ssh, fatal-error

I'm trying to use this package https://github.com/jakeheis/Shout in my ios application but when I build it I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Shout.LibSSH2Error.error(-16): file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.69.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 187
Illegal instruction: 4
```

My `main.swift`:

```
import Shout

let session = try SSH.Session(host: "35.18.24.25")
try session.authenticate(username: "taqo4", privateKey: "~/dora", passphrase: "demo")

let (status, output) = try session.capture("pwd")

print("status: \(status)")
print("output: \(output)")
```

Is there something I need to do/install or with the Shout package?

Thanks in advance!